# Mapping Entity Framework from Existing Database with Custom Field Structure

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api, domain-data-modelling

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with a Code First approach. We use a commercial, off the shelf software solution that I'm rolling up into our own custom application. In addition to having the basic tables for **Employee**, **Salary**, **JobDetail** where this is possible:

```
myEmployee.First " " + myEmployee.Last;
myEmployee.Salary.Where(x => x.SalaryEndDate == null).FirstOrDefault().Amount.ToString();
```

it also has a custom field configuration in the DB like this:

**CustomField** table:

```
GrpID   CstmFldID   CstmFldGrp  CstmFldName
1       1           Education   University
1       2           Education   Degree
1       3           Education   Major
2       1           Logistics   EmergencyEmail
2       2           Logistics   EmergencyPhone  
2       3           Logistics   EmergencyContact
```

**CustomFieldData** table:

```
CstmFldGrpID    CustomField1        CustomField2    CustomField3    EmployeeID
1               George Washington   Bachelors       Philosophy      6548
1               Harvard University  Masters         Business Mgt    4687
2               emerg@contact.com   555-2020        John Adams      6548
2               emerg@harvard.edu   555-0001        Paul Revere     4687
```

How would you go about mapping those custom fields into domain entities? For example, I'd want to be able to write:

```
myEmployee.Education.University.ToString(); 
myEmployee.Logistics.EmergencyPhone.ToString();
```

Comment: For CustomField, you could setup enums. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: Interesting thought. You mean for the Field name? And then use some conditional logic when pulling it in? I feel like that would be less efficient as I'd be pulling in the whole table when I really only need a subset of it.